# Can SQLEXPRESS Authenticate using both SQL And Windows Authentication?

Tags: authentication, sql-server-express

My question is will SQLEXPRESS work in both SQL and Windows authentication modes? I believe the answer is no, but I am not sure.

We have a commercial application that will only work with SQL authentication. We already have a SQLEXPRESS 2008 server, but it is set up for Windows authentication. If I create a user with SQL authentication and try to log in, the Application log says

```
Login failed for user 'cnorton'. 
Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. 
Server is configured for Windows authentication only. 
[CLIENT: 10.100.100.30]
```

So, do I need to deploy a separate SQLEXPRESS server, or are there settings unknown to me right now, that would allow both authentication modes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify what version of SQL Server Express you're running but as far as I know this has always been and still is possible. The following article details how to do it with SQL Server Express 2012.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Joeqwerty is correct, the link he provided will work for 2008 as well.

Answer (score 3):

yes we can authenticate both ways. Please follow the following steps:

- Download and install SQL Server Managment Studio (SSMS).
- Use SSMS to connect to your server, use Windows Authentication
- Right-click server - Properties - Security tab
- Select "SQL Server and Windows authentication mode" click OK button
- Right-click server - Select Restart
- Go to node Security-Logins
- Right-click on login "sa", select properties
- Enter password (twice) on the general tab
- Select Status tab
- Select "Grant" under "Permission to connect to database engine"
- Select "Enabled" under "Login"
- Click OK